# Will we go back(?) to fixed-point arithmetic in the near future?

Tags: language-agnostic, floating-point

As far as I recall, this has been the ongoing trend of the past, I'm just a student, so I might be wrong:

- Long ago: Integer numbers and calculations. Very precise, however cannot present a big range.
- At a later point: Added single-precision floating point numbers (`floats`), and also added FPU's which are incredibly fast at calculating with them.
- Quite recently(?): Double-precision floating point numbers (`doubles`) are starting to become more common. For example in OpenGL Shader Language they are steadily introducing more and more methods that work with doubles natively. I think they are also working on FPU's for doubles?

But also there has been a change to 64-bit processing a few years ago, so I've got a few questions:

- Are there more options now to calculate with fixed-point numbers (maybe two int64 registers?)?
- Why are there, as far as I know, no specific units for fast integer calculation with respect to fixed-point numbers?

Maybe most of what I'm saying does not make much sense, but I think the question remains valid. Is there a switch we switch to fixed-point arithmetic in the near future?

Comment: What makes you think `double` is a recent addition?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I has been around for a quite a long time, I know, but only relatively recently GPU shaders are starting to implement them for example. While `float`s have been around there since the start.

Comment: Double precision floats have been around since the 1960s.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the 2nd questions. There are SIMD operations, where big part are fixed pointer operations (8 and 16 bit). Also, floating point will never be as fast as fixed point operations.

Comment: @BЈовић On many platforms, floating point arithmetic already is as fast as anything can be, namely with throughput of 1 op/cycle/FPU. Latency is not always as good, but that's partly due to pipelining trading latency for throughput, and irrelevant in many performance-sensitive situations. Sure, it takes more complicated circuitry, but you didn't say anything about that ;-)

Comment: @delnan No, I didn't, because I do not care if they put little people to do the job, as long as it works fine. Yes, it is fast, but it still can not do multiply and add in one cycle.

Comment: @BЈовић Of course you can. That's what I just said. For example, [ARM Cortex-A9 FPUs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0408h/ch02s03s02.html) have a *throughput* of 1 op/cycle for FADD and FMUL, meaning you get one addition/multiplication result per cycle. Or are you talking about latency? Then consider: On the same processor, [*integer* multiplication](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0388e/Babghcej.html) also has several cycles latency.

Comment: @delnan neat. so that means that floating point operations faster then fixed point operation... on that platform

Comment: @BЈовић: Floating point multiplication and division are also faster than integral ones on x86+x87 at least since pentium. And on x86+x87 they were always done in 10-byte `long double` precision.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

There is not a snowball's chance in Hell that numerical computing will switch (back) to fixed-point arithmetic in the near future, or in ANY future.

There are several reasons for this, the biggest one being that doing fixed-point arithmetic requires that the programmer keep track of the final position of the decimal (binary) point in the calculation.  This is a LOT of work.  The whole point of floating-point arithmetic is to let the computer do the decimal (binary) point bookkeeping, and let the programmer worry about the algorithm.

Key concept: You do not want to run your computation out to the limits of machine accuracy and precision, as some computations take a LONG time to converge to that limit.  You just want to get an answer that is "good enough" for your particular purposes.  Usually, this is quite a bit less than what the machine in theory can do.

There do exist fast integer multipliers, in the world of integer digital signal processors.  Hardware integer divide exists on some processors, but not all.  There just isn't that much call for it, as integer division is not that common, and there isn't that much that call for it, compared to the on-chip real estate required to make it much faster than doing it in software, or compared to the difference in effort for integer division vs. floating-point division.

EDIT: To clarify, based on a comment: A floating-point divide unit requires an integer divider inside it, and then some extra stuff to handle normalization of the result mantissa and calculation of the result exponent.  The extra stuff is small compared to the integer divider itself.  Once you are providing floating-point addition, subtraction, and multiplication, and you decide to provide integer division, the extra cost of providing floating-point division is generally small.

The Control Data 6600 initially provided four-function floating point, and integer addition, subtraction, and multiplication, but did NOT provide integer division.  It wasn't seen as critically necessary for the machine's core customer base.  The CDC engineers later noticed that they could use the double-precision floating-point hardware to provide a reduced-range (48 bits vs. 60 bits) integer divide capability, almost for free.

One large Freescale (Motorola) integer DSP that I know of provides a "divide step" instruction: The programmer must stack as many of those instructions as he needs bits in his result to do a full-up division.  It is a fair pain to use.  I had to deal briefly with it a few years ago, while troubleshooting a normalized least mean squares (adaptive filter) application.

Read Hamming's [Numerical Methods for Scientists and Engineers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486652416).  (Dover Press is the student's friend.)  In the very beginning of the book, he goes into some detail about why floating-point is used for numerical computation.  Also, ask around the EE department, and see if they have a digital signal processing elective.

Comment: Doesn't floating point division internally require an integer division for the significand?

Comment: @delnan: Yes, of course.  However, the results then have to be renormalized, and final exponents calculated.

Comment: I asked because I misread and thought you implied floating point division is somehow easier than integer division.

Comment: @delnan: The key concept is that floating-point operations (all of them, not just division) are easier FOR THE PROGRAMMER, and not much harder for the machine.  Fixed-point integer computation requires the programmer to do a huge amount of MANUAL bookkeeping to keep track of the decimal (binary) point.  This is the kind of thing that computers (at first, software libraries) and hardware (later) are very good at.  Read Hamming's book.

Comment: Yes, I got that the first time around. I was talking about easier to implement, based on a misunderstanding of your *fifth* paragraph.

Comment: Fixed point operations normally means that the operations are done in integers in suitable fractions of the unit. So the position of decimal/binary point is always the same. So the programmer is not doing any bookkeeping. But of course it quickly looses precision when the numbers are of different order.

Comment: @JanHudec: Yes and no.  In order to do a fixed-point addition or subtraction, the two numbers must have the binary point IN THE SAME PLACE, or one of them must be shifted to line up the binary points.  (Think about adding 12.34 to 0.000125.)  On a multiplication or division, you have to consider the two arguments, each with a known binary point position, and figure out where the result binary point shows up.  (Consider multiplying or dividing 12.34 by 0.00125.)  Avoiding those headaches are why floating-point was invented.  Read Hamming's book.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: Fixed point numbers ALWAYS HAVE the binary point in the same place. That's why they are called FIXED-point. So addition and subtraction are simple. What does make it headache though is that you always have to think about overflow or underflow on multiplication and division.

Comment: @JanHudec: Again, yes and no.  A particular fixed-point type will always have the binary point assumed at a certain position.  However, two DIFFERENT fixed-point types may not have the binary point in the same place.  It is not usually necessary to add or subtract different fixed-point types.  However, they get multiplied, and the results summed (sum-of-products, also known as FIR filter) *ALL* *THE* *TIME*.  Depending on what you are doing, you may have to rescale the sum.  (Think about normalized least mean squares filter processing.)  (Note: I do this for a living.)

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: In older languages with fixed-point type support, each fixed-point type was actually a family of types, and compilers could behave sensibly when operating on mixtures of types (e.g. one could multiply a a 4.2 unit price field by an integer and store it in a 6.2 line-item price field, and add that to an 8.2 total-price field).  Most modern languages would have no way of doing that with user-defined types unless each type was coded separately and separate conversion operators were defined for every pair of source and destination types.  On the other hand, a 32.32 ...

Comment: ...binary fixed-point type, and a 128-bit quasi-decimal fixed-point type (either with a 96-bit integer part and a 32-bit "billionth" part, or a 128-bit number of billionths) could probably take care of many usage cases [for machines with floating-point units, a `double` would often outperform a 32+32 fixed-point type, but on something like a Cortex M3, a 32+32 type would be very useful].

Comment: @supercat, the only languages I ever heard of of with support for that kind of fixed-point were PL/I and COBOL.  As far as I know, PL/I never got much traction outside the IBM mainframe world, and COBOL never got traction outside of business data processing, which was (and still is) almost entirely IBM mainframes.  Oh, and the correct notation is PICTURE 99V99, if memory serves me.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: I never learned COBOL--just PL/I.  And I thought FORTRAN also had some variable types that were something like that.  Certainly a lot of assembly-language programmers make use of a variety of fixed-point types of various sizes, and user-specifiable-sized types would frequently be useful on 8-bit processors if compilers supported them.

Comment: @supercat, I dealt with FORTRAN on CDC 60-bit machines, DEC PDP-10, SDS 930 and Xerox Sigma 5 (very briefly), IBM 1130 (VERY briefly), Univac 1108, Harris supermini, Perkin-Elmer 3252, and TI 990.  I never encountered a FORTRAN with anything like those fixed-point types.  IBM might have snuck something into one of their FORTRAN compilers, I don't know.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: PL/I was the third language I learned after BASIC, and I remember liking it in some ways. I don't really remember how types interacted, but I think modern languages' numerical types could use improvement. One thing I'd really like to see would be a clean separation between "wrapping" types and non-wrapping types (which could further be subdivided into "checked" and "fast"). The reason the signed-vs-unsigned rules in C are quirky is that some C programs use unsigned types to represent things that wrap, and other programs use them to represent numbers. If C had new types...

Comment: ...for things which should wrap when out of range, and things which would trigger UB when out of range, compilers could yield numerically-sensible behavior when using signed and unsigned *numbers* (independent of the size of `int`), and restrict interoperation of wrapping and non-wrapping types to those which would unambiguously make sense. Operations on a 16-bit wrapping type should be performed as though every step wraps to 16 bits, regardless of the size of `int`; operations on mixed-sized wrapping types should be forbidden (unless one is converted to a number or to the other type).